# AzureSignalR with Xamarin - NegotiateAsync response 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: signalr, azure-signalr, net6.0-android

I am facing an issue that `/nagotiate` request fails with 401(Unauthorized).

> Server

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR(options => {
                options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            })
            .AddAzureSignalR(options =>
            {
                options.InitialHubServerConnectionCount = 1;
                options.ConnectionString = "xxxx"

            });
}

protected virtual void ConfigureAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = $"{AzureB2CConfig.Instance}/{AzureB2CConfig.Domain}/{AzureB2CConfig.SignUpSignInPolicyId}/v2.0/";
            options.Audience = AzureB2CConfig.Audience;

            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    var authToken = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");

                    var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken) &&
                        (path.StartsWithSegments("/myhubs")))
                    {
                        context.Token = authToken;
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };

            options.TokenValidationParameters =
                new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    LifetimeValidator = (before, expires, token, param) =>
                    {
                        return expires > DateTime.UtcNow;
                    },
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateActor = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false
                };
        });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowedUser", policy =>
        {
            policy.Requirements.Add(new AllowedUserRequirement());
        });
    });

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseFileServer();
    app.UseEndpoints(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<MyHub>($"/myhubs");
        
    });

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

> Client

```
 var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .WithUrl(SignalRServerUrl, options =>
  {
      options.AccessTokenProvider = authenticationService.GetAccessToken; // returns valid access token
  })
  .WithAutomaticReconnect()
  .Build();

 await Policy
     .Handle<Exception>()
     .WaitAndRetryAsync(1, x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
     .ExecuteAsync(() => _connection.StartAsync()); // causes 401 Unauthorized
```

I have tried many things but none of them helped.

I have read a lots of articles and here is example. [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-6.0), [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/34673), [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/535932/xamarin-android-throws-error-ssl-routinesopenssl-i.html), [this](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6351#issuecomment-932944425), [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12001), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54380097/signalr-core-2-1-jwt-authentication-hub-negotiate-401-unauthorized),[this](https://www.codemag.com/article/1807061/Build-Real-time-Applications-with-ASP.NET-Core-SignalR), [this](https://www.koskila.net/how-to-access-claims-of-a-signalr-user-in-asp-net-core/) and have spend few days for finding the solution but could not..

Are there any missing configuration?

FrameWork: .Net6

**Updated at 20th Oct 2022**

I Added `services.AddAuthorization()` parts and Authentication is now success between the app and the server. But app connects to Azure SignalR. This Azure SignalR authentication is failing. 401