# I am trying to access a SignalR server with JWT Bearer authorization, but i keep getting a 401

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to access a SignalR server with JWT Bearer authorization, but i keep getting a 401. This used to work before but for some reason it's not working anymore, and I don't remember changing anything. I've tried issuing new keys so that way I can make sure they are not expired.
this is the SignalR hub in question

```
using BackEnd_ASP.NET.Entities;
using BackEnd_ASP.NET.Wrappers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Collections;
using System.Numerics;

namespace BackEnd_ASP.NET
{
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

    public class GameHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public static Dictionary<int, String> _PlayerConnectionId = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        public static List<Player> _Players = new List<Player>();
        public GameHub(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            this._context = context;
        }

        #region Overrides
      

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
        {
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {   
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
        
        public async Task JoinQueue(string userEmail)
        {
            Player player1 = _context.Players.Where(x => x.Email == userEmail).FirstOrDefault();
            Player player2 = null;  
            if (player1 != null)
            {
                if (!_Players.Contains(player1) && !_PlayerConnectionId.ContainsKey(player1.PlayerId))
                {
                    _Players.Add(player1);
                    _PlayerConnectionId.Add(player1.PlayerId, Context.ConnectionId);
                }
                
            }
            else
                return;

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("QueuePlayerCountUpdate", _Players.Count);

            bool foundMatch = false;
            int eloRange = 50;
            player2 = FindOpponent(player1);
            string player1ConnectionId = _PlayerConnectionId[player1.PlayerId];
            string player2ConnectionId = _PlayerConnectionId[player2.PlayerId];
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(player2ConnectionId, player1.Email + " " + player2.Email);
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(player1ConnectionId, player1.Email + " " + player2.Email);
            await Clients.Group(player1.Email + " " + player2.Email).SendAsync("MatchFound",player1.Email + " " + player2.Email);
            _Players.Remove(player1);
            _Players.Remove(player2);
            _PlayerConnectionId.Remove(player1.PlayerId);
            _PlayerConnectionId.Remove(player2.PlayerId);
            
        }

        public Player FindOpponent(Player player1)
        {
            Player player2 = null; 
            bool foundMatch = false;
            int eloRange = 50;
            while (!foundMatch)
            {
                
                player2 = _Players.Where(x => player1.Elo - eloRange <= x.Elo && x.Elo <= player1.Elo + eloRange
                && x.PlayerId != player1.PlayerId
                ).FirstOrDefault();
                if (player2 == null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    eloRange += 50;
                }
                else
                {
                    return player2;
                   
                }
            }
            return player2;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

this is the startup file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

namespace BackEnd_ASP.NET
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                var frontendURL = Configuration.GetValue<string>("frontend_url");
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials();
                });
            });

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().
                AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(
                options =>
                {
                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                    {
                        OnMessageReceived = context =>
                        {
                            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                            {
                                context.Token = accessToken;
                            }
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                   

                });
            services.AddSignalR();


        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }


            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<GameHub>("/GameHub");

            });


        }
    }
}
```

and this is the client

```
const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().
            withUrl("https://localhost:7244/GameHub",{
                accessTokenFactory: ()=> {return `${token}`},  
                skipNegotiation: true,
                transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
              }).
            configureLogging(LogLevel.Information).build();
```

I am only getting the 401 if i remove the skip negotiation part, otherwise i get an
"Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.
at webSocket.onclose (WebSocketTransport.ts:136:1)" error.
I tried placing a breakpoint in the code that deconstructs the jwt token from the string query parameters, and it gets there, but I don't know exactly what happens next.
If i remove the [Authorization] attribute, everything works as expected.

Comment: i have also checked the token that was being generated by the server and the one on the client, and they are the same.

Comment: Please [using the sample code official doc recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0#built-in-jwt-authentication-1) to test it works or not ?

Comment: And if the issue still occurs, please try to use `var accessToken = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]
            .FirstOrDefault()?.Replace("Bearer ", "");` in your code.  If it still not works, you also can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54380097/signalr-core-2-1-jwt-authentication-hub-negotiate-401-unauthorized) to troubleshoot.